# Slicing cells in Google docs

Tags: google-docs

Exported data from Arcmap to Google Docs.

Coordinates have excessive amounts of decimal data, is there a fast way to shorten the data?

IE: 123456.7890 --> 123456

I don't mean just displaying shortened values, I mean actually eliminating the data after each decimal point.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `TRUNC` function to eliminate the fractional portion of each number.

```
=trunc(A1)
```

If cell A1 contains 123456.7890, this function will return 123456.